# How to fix stackblitz ngcc error with Material Design MatTableModule?

Tags: angular, angular-material, stackblitz

After reviewing everything between my own project config, and that of [this sample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/yrqnbnrqqpb), I am unable to know why I get the error:

> Error in turbo_modules/@angular/material@9.2.4/table/table-module.d.ts (8:22)
>
> Appears in the NgModule.exports of MaterialModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.
>
> This likely means that the dependency (@angular/material/table) which declares MatTableModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc.

Image from Stackblitz:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I had read something about Ivy being an issue, and while I was scouting around the Settings area of my Stackblitz project I noticed this checkbox labelled "Ivy".  Although it was unchecked, I checked it.  After a refresh I still got the error.  I unchecked it, and refreshed.  Error gone!

[image]

Comment: For me, it was checked. As soon as I unchecked it. it worked. Thanks.