# Angular Material upgrade from version 13 to 14 issue - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, migration

During the migration of Angular and Angular Material from version 13.2.6 to 14.2.2 I have faced below issues:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor' or its corresponding type declarations.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof MatInputBase' is not assignable to parameter of type '_AbstractConstructor'.
> Types of construct signatures are incompatible.

which affected every file where `Constructor` and `AbstractConstructor` were used.

I have found [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692357/error-node-modules-angular-material-core-common-behaviors-constructor-d-ts14) but it seems just the error message is similar but none of the suggestions was helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usually, the error message is pretty clear - "Cannot find module" means the module is not there :)

In order to find out if this is true, I went to `node_modules` folder and then `@angular/material/core/` just to confirm there is no `common-behaviors` folder there. However in the `index.t.ts` file inside core module I could find below declarations:

```
export declare type _Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export declare type _AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

It basically means that the code was moved out around during the refactoring and some things changed place. In order to fix my issue I simple needed to change the imports to correct path, from:

```
import { AbstractConstructor, Constructor } from '@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor';
```

to:

```
import { _AbstractConstructor, _Constructor } from '@angular/material/core';
```

Obviously the code needs to be adjusted a bit, because now these classes are coming with `_` in the front of the name.

Easy, but not obvious, especially it wasn't mentioned in the [Angular Migration guide](https://update.angular.io/) neither managed by upgrade script itself.